# How to get rid of the red areas and what are they?

Tags: tabs, newlines

I have some code I copy-paste from somewhere. What is this how to get rid of them all at once?

[image]

My emacs is setup to automatically cut the orange areas, but to get rid of these?

update:

```
             position: 16165 of 16950 (95%), column: 0
            character: TAB (displayed as TAB) (codepoint 9, #o11, #x9)
    preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x09
               script: latin
               syntax:      which means: whitespace
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET HEX-CODEPOINT" or "C-x 8 RET NAME"
          buffer code: #x09
            file code: #x09 (encoded by coding system undecided-unix)
              display: by display table entry [?→ ? ] (see below)

The display table entry is displayed by these fonts (glyph codes):
→: xft:-MS  -Consolas-normal-normal-normal-*-23-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x365)
    : -- no font --

Character code properties: customize what to show
  old-name: CHARACTER TABULATION
  general-category: Cc (Other, Control)
  decomposition: (9) (' ')

There is an overlay here:
 From 16165 to 16165
  before-string        [Show]
  linum-str            [Show]


There are text properties here:
  face                 whitespace-tab
  fontified            t
```

Comment: Did you accidentally activate [`whitespace-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html)? If not, does the problem persist if you shut down Emacs and open it up again?

Comment: @TianxiangXiong, no. it's not the code I've written.

Comment: Are you *sure* you didn't activate `whitespace-mode`? That looks a lot like `whitespace-mode`. `M-x whitespace-mode` to deactivate.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong, I'm sure --` "(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)"` . But as I've said, those areas are red, whereas  'delete-trailing-whitespace deletes only orange ones.

Comment: What happens if you do `M-x whitespace-mode`? Does it turn off the red highlighting of whitespace? If so, then @TianxiangXiong was right. Something in your init file (presumably) was turning on `whitespace-mode`.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong is not talking about `delete-trailing-whitespace`. We are talking about `whitespace-mode`.

Comment: @Drew, nothing happens.

Comment: @Drew, ok, i've disabled it. However, how can I automatically delete them similar to `delete-trailing-whitespace`?

Comment: OK. What happens if you put the cursor somewhere in the red area and you use `C-u C-x =`? Post what it tells you, near the bottom, about text properties or overlays (e.g. faces).

Comment: You've disabled what? Automatically delete what?

Comment: @Drew, yes. Automatically delete the whitespaces on save -- red-areas -- or whatever it is.

Comment: You are highlighting Tab characters. Do `C-h f whitespace-mode`, then click the link for `whitespace-styles`. Change the style to not include highlighting Tab chars.

Comment: @Drew, **Automatically on save**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, OP is an Emacs newbie trying to turn tabs into spaces in his buffer.

Try the following:

```
(customize-set-variable 'indent-tabs-mode nil)
(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'whitespace-cleanup)
```

You don't need `delete-trailing-whitespace` anymore.

Comment: what does that do?

Comment: But maybe he just wants to stop highlighting Tabs, instead of converting them to spaces. `whitespace-styles` is where to do that. Also, turning off `indent-tabs-mode` doesn't convert existing Tabs. For that, you need to use `untabify`: `C-x h` to select all the text, then `M-x untabify`.

Comment: @Drew, I don't want to stop highlighting Tabs,

Comment: select the whole buffer, then M-x untabify might be what you want. @Drew mentioned it...

Comment: `untabify` will remove tabs from the current buffer; putting `whitespace-cleanup` in `before-save-hook` will eliminate all future whitespace problems.

Comment: this doesn't work.